# How can I get a liquid footer to stick to the bottom using CSS for Internet Explorer?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, tumblr

I checked my Tumblr theme on IE and the footer is in the middle of the page and here is the code I have.

```
#mastfooter {
    background-color: #4F3117;
    height: 295px;
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: -38px;
}
```

Is there an Internet Explorer 9 solution to that?

Comment: can you share a link to the page?

Comment: what's your html - ie where does the #mastfooter sit?

Comment: @davidb-Here's a link to the page.

http://lt-chocolate.tumblr.com/

Answer (score 0):

Ryan Fait has the best cross browser solution to a sticky footer

[See Here](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/)

But there are countless examples of sticky footers using just CSS on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code provided, I would guess that you need to change it to something like this-

```
#mastfooter {
background-color: #4F3117;
height: 295px;
clear: both;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
width: 100%;
position: fixed; /* keeps the footer visible even when scrolling*/
bottom: 0px;
```

}

Note that the top and bottom margins have been removed, they were most likely the cause of the positioning problem.